# Boost Regulator Vin greater than Vout

Tags: boost

Looking at using Boost regulator TPS61031PWPR or TPS61091RSAR to output 3.3V in a battery application. What would Vout be if the Vin is greater than 3.3V? What is the V drop on the output  if this Vin is greater than 3.3V?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site (maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, please ask on electronics.stackexchange.com instead.